# Access denied when running Mysql in Kubernetes

Tags: java, mysql, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

i'm a newbie to Kubernetes. This is my situation: 
I found a open-source project on Github, it is a online bookstore: `https://github.com/devdcores/BookStoreApp-Distributed-Application` (anyway, thankss to author of this repo). This project is written in microservice-architecture, it had a docker-compose to build and run container instantly. I've try and it worked.
But when i try to build and run this project in Kubernetes and Helm, problem raise: 
Some service cannot connect to mysqldb: *Access denied for user 'bookstoreDBA'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)*. So i look into source code and found this:

```
datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://bookstore-mysql-db:3306/bookstore_db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: bookstoreDBA
    password: PaSSworD
```

My question is: Is the `url` set up properly? Is it the reason cause problem? If it is (not), then how to fix this problem? 
P/S: These are environment variables and *service.yaml* for mysql container:

```
env:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: bookstore_db
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: PaSSworD
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r00tPaSSworD
    MYSQL_USER: bookstoreDBA

# service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: bookstore-mysql-db
  name: bookstore-mysql-db
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "3306"
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: bookstore-mysql-db
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Your username or password is incorrect.

Comment: That's certainly a queer host name, but I'm guessing that might be something to do with Docker (I don't know Docker)
Try issuing the following MySql command *as root* `GRANT ALL ON bookstore_db.* TO 'bookstoreDBA'@'172.17.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PaSSworD';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use *mysql client* to create `bookstoreDBA` user and grant needed privileges. Then restart the cluster. Now every things work properly.